# Adding lists of objects to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on some code that would take in a "game" object and put it into a Firebase database. Each game has a name and an arraylist of "Players" who each have a name and a "target". When I run the code however the app just crashes with no clear error, it just states it cannot execute the method. Im sure It has something to do with the list of players as earlier I could get it to work with just the name of the game.

```
public void beginGame(View view) {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    EditText gameNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gameName);
    String gameName = gameNameField.getText().toString().trim();
    Collections.shuffle(players);
    if (gameName.isEmpty()) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.toast_no_game_name, duration);
        toast.show();

    } else if (playerNames.size() < 2) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.toast_not_enough_players, duration);
        toast.show();

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            if (i != (players.size() - 1)) {
                players.get(i).target = players.get(i + 1);
            } else {
                players.get(i).target = players.get(0);
            }
        }
        Game game = new Game(gameName, players);
        mDatabase.child("Games").child(gameName).setValue(game);

        Intent intent = new Intent(StartNewGameActivity.this, SessionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

To be clear I want my data base organized as such:

```
Games:
    Game1:
        name: Johns Game
        Players: 
             John
             Mike

    Game2:......
```

**EDIT 1**
The players are initialized in a dialog that asks for a player name and then passes the player to the array list.

```
public void addNewPlayer(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new CreatePlayerDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Player");
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(String name) {
    playerNames.add(name);
    players.add(new Player(name));
}
```

And here is the error from my Logcat

```
11-26 12:15:29.780 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hunte.assassin, PID: 10730
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbq
11-26 12:15:29.780 10730-10740/com.example.hunte.assassin I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6950(796KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 136MB/136MB, paused 42.643ms total 65.881ms
11-26 12:15:30.129 1761-1821/? V/WindowOrientationListener: Proposed rotation changed! : currentRotation=0, proposedRotation=0, oldProposedRotation=-1, predictedRotation=0, timeDeltaMS=66.65039, isAccelerating=false, isFlat=false, isSwinging=false, isOverhead=false, isTouched=false, timeUntilSettledMS=0.0, timeUntilAccelerationDelayExpiredMS=0.0, timeUntilFlatDelayExpiredMS=0.0, timeUntilSwingDelayExpiredMS=0.0, timeUntilTouchDelayExpiredMS=0.0
11-26 12:15:30.188 1761-2477/? D/sensors_hal_LGMotionAccel: processInd: LP2: X: 1.027176 Y: 4.640945 Z: 8.011398 SAM TS: 153411799 HAL TS:135753777272948 elapsedRealtimeNano:135753856670678
11-26 12:15:30.311 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-26 12:15:30.311 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
11-26 12:15:30.311 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: file=Method.java
11-26 12:15:30.311 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: class=java.lang.reflect.Method
11-26 12:15:30.311 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: method=invoke line=-2
11-26 12:15:30.381 10730-10730/com.example.hunte.assassin D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi
11-26 12:15:30.383 10730-10730/? D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 20167208
11-26 12:15:30.383 10730-10730/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 20167300)
11-26 12:15:30.383 10730-10730/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 20167300 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4547)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Can you post the portion where players is initialized ? Also exactly is in your Logcat ?

Comment: @rhari edits have been made in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out I didnt have an accurate player constructor (it didnt actually take in a name) but im posting my code in case has a similar question in the future

```
public void beginGame(View view) {
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

    EditText gameNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gameName);
    String gameName = gameNameField.getText().toString().trim();
    Collections.shuffle(players);
    if (gameName.isEmpty()) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.toast_no_game_name, duration);
        toast.show();

    } else if (playerNames.size() < 2) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.toast_not_enough_players, duration);
        toast.show();

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            if (i != (players.size() - 1)) {
                players.get(i).target = players.get(i + 1);
            } else {
                players.get(i).target = players.get(0);
            }
        }
        Game game = new Game(gameName, players);
        DatabaseReference gamesRef = ref.child("Games").child(gameName).child("players");
        Map<String, Player> gamePlayers = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
            Player currentPlayer = players.get(i);
            gamesRef.child(currentPlayer.getName()).setValue(currentPlayer);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not have many values under one child. Try to set values one by one, each time creating a new child for each new player. mDatabase.child("Games").child(gameName).child(playerName); where playerName is changed (i++ incrementing inside the array list) and new child is created for each item.